# USB Controller drivers do not reinstall after desinstallation

Tags: usb, drivers

After plugging in an Apple Keyboard on a Win XP running PC, all USB ports stopped functioning.

Steps that failed:
Updating drivers
Rollback drivers
Uninstalling the USB Controller drivers and restarting the PC
Reinstalling drivers from the web, WINDOWS driver cache, i386, WINDOWS startup CD, ..
Disabling and reanabling USB in BIOS
Reinstalling SP3
System restore

Everytime I start up the PC, WINDOWS prompts me to reinstall USB drivers, but they cannot be located...

I really would like to avoid having to do a clean reinstall...

I was wondering if altering the registery could help, but I cannot figure out what.
PS: setting  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\USB to 1 did not help either

Thanks for helping,

Ollie

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
[Nirsoft USB Devices](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html)

I had a similar problem with other device and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I can view my USB devices now, and everything seems OK. The problem is that the PC does not recognize the root/generic USB or something. I therefore cannot reinstall my drivers.
There is still power running through the USB ports, so I guess I did not fry them...